# How I can loop through the ZStack of flashcards views without using ForEach loop in Swift UI?

Tags: ios, swift, loops, swiftui

I want to build a View with ZStack of cards which get info from an array. Cards have to swipe to the left and to the right by .gesture modifier, without any other buttons. What I want is when the current card is displayed, the next card isn't seen. And when the current card goes away, the next card automatically is shows up.

Long story short, I want to make swipe cards UI like in Tinder or Quizlet, without using Foreach and laying out all the cards at once (there may be a lot of them)

I tried to loop through ForEach(array.indices) without any modifiers, and all cards displayed simultaneously in a stack, but I want them to update as user swipes the current card. I don't know of other ways to write code for updating views (beginner here).

```
struct ContentView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var model: Model
var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        ZStack {
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .aspectRatio(CGSize(width: 150, height: 300), contentMode: .fit)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .shadow(radius: 5)
                .padding(50)
            
            ForEach(model.flashcard.reversed()) { card in
                AllCardView(flashcard: Flashcard(front: card.front, back: card.back))
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: So you want only 1 card on the screen at a time and you want to swipe the cards? Clue: Use `DragGesture()`, `.offset`, `withAnimation { //set the offset }`. Play around with it.

Comment: If you are new to SwiftUI, start with something small before building an app. Start small so that you are not overwhelmed, once you are more familiar you can dig deeper

Comment: thank you for your answer! I set myself a challenge and it really interests me :) so that's why I want to figure it out. I use DragGesture, .offset  and withAnimation modifiers already in my Card View. I have a problem with the stack of all cards.

Comment: Post the code and show where exactly is the problem in your attempt

Comment: I posted the code. Here I use ForEach loop to show all cards simultaneously in the ZStack. But I want just one card to be displayed on the screen, and only when user swipes away the card, the function calls the next item in the array of the next card and it appears on the screen in the same place.

Comment: You are on the right track, on `AllCardView` add the gesture. I can't post my attempt because it isn't perfect. This is quite a bit of work, so break into smaller steps and try.

Answer (score 1):

#### Approach:

- Use `ZStack` to stack the cards
- Add `DragGesture` on the card
- Use the `.onChanged` and `.onEnded` on the gesture to move the card
- Rotate the card
- Add offset to the card
- Use `withAnimation { }` to animate the value changes

Given below is a crude implementation, you could use it as a guidance and refine it:

#### Card:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct Card: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let color: Color
}
```

#### Model:

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var cards = [
        Card(id: 1, title: "1", color: .red),
        Card(id: 2, title: "2", color: .green),
        Card(id: 3, title: "3", color: .blue),
        Card(id: 4, title: "4", color: .yellow),
        Card(id: 5, title: "5", color: .purple),
        Card(id: 6, title: "6", color: .orange),
    ]
    
    func removeFirstCard() {
        guard !cards.isEmpty else {
            return
        }
        cards.remove(at: 0)
    }
}
```

#### CardView:

```
struct CardView: View {
    let title: String
    let color: Color
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var model: Model
    
    private let xthreshold = CGFloat(150)
    private let yMovement = CGFloat(10)
    
    @State private var xOffset = CGFloat(0)
    @State private var yOffset = CGFloat(0)
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 18)
                .foregroundColor(color)
            Text(title)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 400)
        .gesture(dragGesture)
        .offset(x: xOffset, y: yOffset)
        .rotationEffect(rotationAngle, anchor: rotationAnchor)
    }
    
    var rotationAngle: Angle {
        let degrees: Double
        switch xOffset {
        case 0:
            degrees = 0
        case ...0:
            degrees = -5
        case 0...:
            degrees = 5
        default:
            degrees = 0
        }
        return Angle(degrees: degrees)
    }
    
    var rotationAnchor: UnitPoint {
        xOffset >= 0 ? .topLeading : .topTrailing
    }
    
    var dragGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 20)
            .onEnded { value in
                let xOffset: CGFloat
                let yOffset: CGFloat
                switch self.xOffset {
                case ...(-xthreshold):
                    print("negative")
                    xOffset = -200
                    yOffset = yMovement
                case -xthreshold...0:
                    print("negative - not enough")
                    xOffset = 0
                    yOffset = 0
                case xthreshold...:
                    print("positive")
                    xOffset = 200
                    yOffset = yMovement
                case 0...:
                    print("positive - not enough")
                    xOffset = 0
                    yOffset = 0
                default:
                    print("default")
                    xOffset = 0
                    yOffset = 0
                }
                
                withAnimation {
                    self.xOffset = xOffset
                    self.yOffset = yOffset
                    if xOffset != 0 {
                        model.removeFirstCard()
                    }
                }
            }
            .onChanged { value in
                switch value.translation.width {
                case ...0:
                    print("negative")
                    withAnimation {
                        yOffset = yMovement
                    }
                case 0...:
                    print("positive")
                    withAnimation {
                        yOffset = yMovement
                    }
                default:
                    print("default")
                    withAnimation {
                        yOffset = 0
                    }
                }

                xOffset += value.translation.width
            }
    }
}
```

#### ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = Model()
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(model.cards.reversed()) { card in
                CardView(title: card.title, color: card.color)
                    .environmentObject(model)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have already created a code structure similar to the one you presented in the comment, except for a couple of points. I wanted to clarify: are there any other ways to display CardView inside ContentView except ForEach?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid ForEach?

Comment: Because when I use ForEach in the ContentView, all the cards from the array are displayed at the same time (even if they are in the ZStack). I want to make it so that when the user moves the top card across the screen, the bottom card is not visible (and not there at all). And for the bottom card to be displayed (appear) on the ContentView screen only when the top card is swiped off the screen.

Comment: IMHO you only need to display top 2 cards at a given time. Once the top card is swiped out of the screen, then a new card could be added to the array. New items could be added to the bottom of the deck dynamically when the top card is gone. So ForEach is fine. It is unto you to manage the model.cards

Comment: I 100% agree, that is exactly what I would like to do. But I'm struggling with how to do it. Can you please elaborate on how one would do it that way?

Comment: Keep `ForEach` as it is, nothing wrong with it. Based on my example, once the animation is completed (.onEnded) and if the card is swiped off, then add more cards to model.cards. Since view is using `model` as an `EnvironmentObject` any changes to the published property cards will cause the view to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need some more Views to transform the data you want to display, e.g.

```
struct CardView: View {
    let cards: [Card]

    var cardsReversed: [Card] {
        cards.reversed()
    }

    var body: some View {
        CardView2(cardsReversed: cardsReversed)
    }
}

struct CardView2: View {
    let cardsReversed: [Card]

    var body: some View {
       ...
    }
}
```

Name the Views however you like.